# When model binding includes a bool what string value must the form collection contain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, boolean

If I am using model binding and one of the variables in the model is a bool what string must the form collection contain to be considered true or false?

So for example if my model has a variable:

> bool isHappy;

Now when the model binder reads the form collection and it contains name "isHappy" what will the value have to be? "true", "checked", "1", etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will be "true" or "false". Note that it's case insensitive so "True", "False", "TRUE", "FALSE" also work.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Here's how I create a Y/N select list for this case:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static SelectList GetYesNoSelectList()
    {
        SelectListItem yesChoice = new SelectListItem { Value = "True", Text = "Y" };
        SelectListItem noChoice = new SelectListItem { Value = "False", Text = "N" };
        List<SelectListItem> yesNoList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        yesNoList.Add(yesChoice);
        yesNoList.Add(noChoice);

        return new SelectList(yesNoList, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```