# How can i save a bool value as 0 or 1 to database in a json body?

Tags: c#, json, api

I have an endpoint as follows:

```
https://myapi/user/1234
```

the body is

```
{
  "ExpiryDays": "50",  
  "Access1": "False",
  "Access2": "True",
  "Access3": "False",
  "Address": "500",
}
```

In the database the columns and datatype are

```
 ExpiryDays  int 
 Access1     bit, not null
 Access2     bit, not null
 Access3     bit, not null
 Address     nvarchar(max)
```

I would have though the False would be converted to a 0 and True to 1 when inserted in the db.

In my model in MVC I have defined the fields as bool.
But i get the error

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]. Path: $.Access1 .

Any ideas as on this ?

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble deserializing a _quoted_ boolean value (true and false do not need to be quoted in JSON, nor do numbers) into a `bool?` in C#. That's a completely separate problem to writing to the database, don't you think?

Comment: You can use bool.TryParse() if your backend is written in c# to parse the string into a bool value.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?view=net-6.0
A bool value can be stored as bit in database.

Comment: Please share your model and controller code so we can advise better

Comment: For JSON, the [correct boolean values](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/boolean.html) are `true` and `false` - lowercase, no quotes

Comment: the model has bool Access1 , after changing to bool? Access1 it works as expected.

Comment: "bool? makes it work".... really I'd check your db to make sure "True" is being saved when you pass that because bool? means you've probably just got NULL in "Access1" because it can't deserialize it. It won't error but it will probably always just default to "False" no matter what you pass in the JSON

Comment: If you are stuck with getting string values for Access1 etc, then use an "api model" that uses string properties there. Before storing you convert that to a "database model" having bool properties. Similar for ExpiryDays that needs to convert from string to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670678/when-model-binding-includes-a-bool-what-string-value-must-the-form-collection-co) - bool should have no quotes. Ideally, it should be in lower case but I don't think it cares that much. You can also use 0 and 1 I think

Also assuming "ExpiryDays" is a number it shouldn't really be quoted either.

Try changing the body to:

```
{
  "ExpiryDays": 50,    
  "Access1": False,
  "Access2": True,
  "Access3": False,
  "Address": "500",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the quotes
for example "Access1": False,